# PHP for loop not getting all posted values

Tags: php

I have a HTML Form where i can add rows dynamically, every time a row is added the number in my input field goes up each time

each row there are 4 input fields and each one has the number on the end of the name

on my submit page i have this PHP for loop:

```
for($x=1;$x<=$_POST["number"];$x++)
{

}
```

but its only getting one posted value

i have tried changing to:

```
for($x=0;$x<=$_POST["number"];$x++)
{

}
```

but this does the same thing

Comment: `var_dump(`$_POST["number"]`);` and show us the result.

Comment: So, thats the problem! you are getting 1 and your loop iterates One time. Dude! the PHP loop is fine, check why your code is not updating the `number` field as you expect it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['number']); $x++)
{
    echo "Number: $_POST['number'][$x]";
}

// OR:

foreach ($_POST['number'] as $number)
{
    echo "Number: $number";
}
```

You have to add the `count()` function and use `<` instead of `<=` or else you will get an:
**index out of range** error.

Comment: see that! it is not an array! an string is there as `$_POST['number']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ($x = 0; $size = count($_POST['number']); $x < size; $x++)
{
    echo "Number: $_POST['number'][$x]";
}
```

Bad practice:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['number']); $x++)
{
    echo "Number: $_POST['number'][$x]";
}
```

Why? The array size is fetched on every iteration and this will make your code run slower.

Comment: He said the `$_POST["number"]` is string and your solution works on array!